# How do I hold down left click in AutoKey

Tags: autokey

I'm using the latest autokey version. The github page only explains how to send a mouse click (i.e. press and release)

Comment: How does your question relate to this site's topic?  You've mentioned no OS/release details, nor if using desktop/server/IoT appliance etc. Also it's best if you don't assume we're familiar with the project, but provide links...

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by rebinding the thing I wanted to do to a keyboard button

Comment: Can you share your script?